# Can SUMPRODUCT ignore blank cells?

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I am calculating the trend lines for several hundred data sets, using the Least Squares Method. I am evaluating a 12 month period for each set. Not all sets have 12 months of data, or even fewer than 12 months of consecutive data. My formula, below, works accurately (ignores blank cells and producing the correct trend value) only if the data points are consecutive, regardless of 12 or i.e., 4 data points.

```
=IF(COUNTA(B504:M504)<=1,0,
         SUMPRODUCT(
                                 $B$2:$M$2-AVERAGE($B$2:$M$2),
                                B504:M504-AVERAGE(B504:M504),
                                 --(B504:M504:B504:M504<>""))
    /
          SUMPRODUCT(POWER(INDIRECT("$B$2"&":"&ADDRESS(2,COUNTA(B504:M504)+1))
          -AVERAGE(INDIRECT("$B$2"&":"&ADDRESS(2,COUNTA(B504:M504)+1))),2)))
```

Any ideas why my formula does not appear to ignore blank cells? Let me know what other information would be helpful!

[Sample of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8gZ8.png)

Comment: Show some data.

Comment: change the --(B504:M504:B504:M504<>"") to --(B504:M504<>"")

Comment: If this still doesn't work, can you reply the formula that you are planning to work out using sum product in mathematical notation like : Ʃ(y-ŷ)(x-x̄) / Ʃ (.....) .....

Comment: included image of data examples, above

Comment: (Σ(x-x̄)(y-y̅))/Σ(x-x̄)^2 and omit blank values in the array of y values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, if anyone would like to know.

I was having a problem using two arrays in sumproduct because one array was in a different order from the corresponding array due to empty cells. I basically did a SMALL MATCH IF function to take the position of the cells, place them in numeric order and then use LOOKUP to find the values of my array to be used in the sum product. Let me know if you would like more specifics. Happy to share.